# Downloading and using Microsoft apps with work email address

Tags: windows-10

I want to download apps from the Microsoft Store on my system. However, I only have a work e-mail address that I use for all my software, such as Onedrive, Outlook etc. When I want to download an app ... I get asked to sign in, followed by "That Microsoft account doesn’t exist. Enter a different account or get a new one."

When I choose to create one, I get the message "You can’t sign up here with a work or school email address. Use a personal email address, such as Gmail or Yahoo!, or get a new Outlook email address.".

Do I seriously need to log in with my private email account? Or do I really need two separate Email addresses to use apps etc, that will then not be synchronised? This seems highly inconvenient. Am I doing something wrong? 
(Using Win10 Home)

Comment: Many enterprises that use Microsoft Office and allow their employees to have Microsoft accounts for work also have "federated" logins - that is, if you log in using your work account, it checks your credentials by interrogating your own organization's Active Directory domain controller(s). These may not be accessible if you attempt to log in from outside your company network. Check with your employer's IT personnel to see if this is the case for you.

Comment: While trying to use the Microsoft Store, are you connected to your work network or are you outside?

Comment: I am inside the work network

Comment: @cheesus - You really should asked your IT department.  Allowing applications to be installed from the Microsoft Store might not be allowed.  Based on the error message, I suspect, your inability to install applications from the store might be intentional.

Answer (score 0):

My work uses Outlook suite but also uses G-Suite (Only Google Drive though we can access an unused Gmail). As a result, my work email can sign into G-Suite. I've been able to use this "Google Account" to use Windows Calendar (the Microsoft desktop app that looks like but isn't Outlook calendar, which is only available as part of the Outlook mail app).

Perhaps you can create a Windows account with a Gmail address (if your work hasn't linked it already).

Otherwise you can create a new account if you don't want to use your personal account.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, simply clicking Cancel on the sign-in prompt allowed me to download Microsoft Store apps. The Profile toolbar widget even correctly shows my Azure Active Directory account.